# How to replace a BMW E36 318 TDS's stereo?

Tags: audio

There seem to be tools needed to extract the previous stereo system (K7 + radio) and I have a a doubt about the necessity of unplugging the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer. I ended up inserting 2 little iron shafts (2mm thick) on each side, and I drew the autoradio out. Didn't disconnect the battery, but put the car's switch on the 2nd position (just before ignition) as recommended by the manual. Everything went fine, except the antenna that seems to be less efficient now.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, you need a really small allen wrench. There should be 2 screws, one on each side, but it's been a while since I've seen one of those. Also, BMW recommends disconnecting the battery when dealing with electronics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up inserting 2 little iron shafts (2mm thick) on each side, and I drew the autoradio out. Didn't disconnect the battery, but put the car's switch on the 2nd position (just before ignition) as recommended by the manual. Everything went fine, except the antenna that seems to be less efficient now.